# WordPress redirect file URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, pdf

I am currently working on a WordPress plugin that enables to set an expire date on uploaded files.

After expire the user should be redirected to a page that says that the current file has been expired.

For example:

Administrator adds a pfd called "myPDF.pdf" on the site and set the expire date to 2 days.

The user can enter the pdf through the link:

> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/myPDF.pdf

The first 2 days its possible for the user to open and read the PDF, after 2 days the user should be redirected to

> http://localhost/wordpress/this-file-was-deleted

Is this possible? I was thinking about a redirect in the .htaccess to

> http://localhost/wordpress/checkfile&q=myPDF.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty much simple, when you upload the file, save meta against it in db with key value, like expiry_date and put value as its expiry date.

When you get that file, just check its expiry if current date is greater then that expiry, redirect to url you want.

You also need to store file url too in the db and loop through those urls and for each check them through $_GET if that url has hit or not.

Comment: That part is indeed easy, but the problem is that you can't execute php code while accessing the file directly by the link http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/myPDF.pdf

Comment: @Matthew, you could redirect all direct file URLs to a php file that does the check, then serves the file, or protect direct file download by using a cookie. There are many ways to accomplish your desired behavior. Also, ensuring the direct URLs aren't exposed in the first place helps.

Comment: offcouse @Matthew you can, in that case you need to store file url too in the db and loop through those urls and for each check them through $_GET if that url has hit or not